# Relative connection strings in c# for SQL Server 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, database-connection, connection-string

I have a Windows form application with database in the folder of the project itself (`.mdf` and `.ldf` files). I have my connection strings in the `app.config` file. I want to use the relative path in `app.config` file so that even if I move the folder to some other drive or pc, it should work. Please help.

Please understand that I want relative path to the database file in `app.config` file and not in the `.cs` files.

Comment: Have you *tried* putting a relative path in the config file?  What happened?

Comment: Yes, I did! I used |DataDirectory| to create a relative path. It was working but I am not sure of it, because after I created a deployement (a setup package) and then installed on another machine, it did not work.

Comment: Perhaps you should describe in more detail your setup package and in what way it didn't work; if it *was* working in one scenario then the problem may not be your relative path.

Comment: **My Setup Package** is just the published project, the default visual studio 2010 feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just using `"directory/file"` will work.

Comment: consider I have all my .cs files and .mdf and .ldf files in the folder QuizMaster. Then will **database.mdf** work?

Comment: They need to be relative to the application path. So if you have your files in Quizmaster, the path needs to be "Quizmaster\file.mdf"

Answer (score 0):

Use the "~". This says that you are in the current working directory.. You can form the relative from this one.